# data not being written to local SQL Server database file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, local

I have written that gets data from a sensor, I am trying to write this data to a local SQL Server database file.

Code doesn't produce any errors but the data is not being written to the data table.

I have used the following code: (any suggestions?)

```
    static void Insert(string date, double value, string deviceName)
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string filename = path + "\\Database1.mdf";
        Console.WriteLine(filename);
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + filename + ";Database=Database1";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

        try
        {
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES(@Id, @Date, @Value, @Device Name)", conn))
                {
                    num11 += 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", num11);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device Name", deviceName);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException es)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(es);
            //Display Error message
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You're inserting async and then closing the connection. Call `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

Comment: Set Database1.mdf's "Copy to Output Directory" property value to "Do not copy" from Properties box.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` to *asynchronously* insert the record - but you're then closing the connection immediately, while the insert has almost certainly not yet completed.

You should either use the synchronous call instead, or use asynchrony properly - probably making the method asynchronous, and awaiting the result of `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`. You need to wait for the operation to complete before you close the connection, basically.

You don't need to call `Close` explicitly at all, by the way - you've already got a `using` statement, so the connection will be disposed as execution exits the block. (It's not clear why you've got an extra block inside the `using` statement either, by the way.)